# mostrar el valor de un data- en un iframe

Tags: html

Hola estoy teniendo problemas para hacer que al presionar un botón se envié una url a un iframe mediate data-

este es mi codigo

```
<button data-video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcJtL7QggTI">Cargar video</button>

<iframe ></iframe>
```

lo que quiero es incertar un video en un iframe pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando jquery puedes hacer algo asi para colocar el atributo src en el iframe

Para poder poner el video debes cambiar la url del video debe llevar el prefijo **/embed/** y debes quitar **watch?v=** de la url asi como en el ejemplo

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  let ifr = $("iframe")[0]
  ifr.src = $(this).data('video')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xcJtL7QggTI">Cargar video</button>

<iframe width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```